# How can I exclude certain users from a command?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a command where there is an `asyncio` event. Unfortunately this is lost when the bot restarts. Therefore I want to be able to exclude certain users from a command, respectively the bot should not react if they are entered in the list.

**My attempt** so far has been the following:

```py
@commands.command
async def test(self, ctx):
#Shortened
user = discord.Member
userlist = [HereWePutTheUserIDs]
if user in userlist:
    return await ctx.send("You are on the blocklist.")
```

Unfortunately, this did nothing. Is there anyway to prevent certain users, by ID/name, from executing the command until I remove them from the list?

Comment: Given you block by ID, you'd need to check if `user.id` is in `userlist`, not the entire user object. The general idea you describe works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning the user to a class, you don't even instantiate it, that's not how it works, the user variable should be `ctx.author.id`

```py
user = ctx.author.id
```